# Parsing a string to datetime in .netcore from format dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

I found similar questions, but none is covered this case.

Im trying to do follows:

```
string dateTime = "28.11.2020 16:08:43"

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but Im getting exception:

```
System.FormatException: String '28.11.2020 16:08:43' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

Comment: Side-note: since Stefan sounds like you come from germany/austria/swiss you use `.` as date separator by default. So why you use `InvariantCulture` and why you use `ParseExact` at all? `DateTime.Parse(dateTime)` would work already. If it can contain invalid formats use `TryParse`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `hh` in your format string, which means "hour of halfday, in the range 1-12". You want `HH`, which means "hour of day, in the range 0-23". The actual value (16) isn't in the range 1-12, hence the error.

Any time you run into date/time formatting or parsing issues, it's worth checking your date/time format *very, very* carefully against the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).